# Using node-sass watch option with yarn start script

Tags: sass

so i am trying to run sass with yarn start at the same time.

when i `run yarn build:sass` in command line , it triggesr the sass watch and if I make any changes into the sass it will update the css file however it wont start the project "`yarn start` doesnt work"   is there anyway for me to run it all in one console?

```
"build:sass": "node-sass src dist",
"watch:css": "yarn build:sass && yarn build:sass -- -w && yarn start",
"start": "PUBLIC_URL=/ react-scripts start",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone out there  u can run this using run all
install the package first and then have it run after

```
start": "npm-run-all -p watch:sass start:react"
```